# Akka Stream throttle and ask pattern

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I previously used TimerBasedThrottler from akka.contrib but now has been deprecated and replaced with akka stream throttle. This is my actor

```scala
class MyActor extends Actor{

    def receive = {
        case Message(msg) =>
        val date = LocalDateTime.now()
        println(s"getting: $msg @ $date from ${sender()}")
        sender() ! s"$msg ack"
    }
}
```

This is my throttler

```scala
val throttler = Source.actorRef(bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
                      .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
                      .to(Sink.actorRef(myActor, NotUsed))
                      .run()
```

And I use it like this:

```
val res = (throttler ? MyActor.Message("hello")).mapTo[String]
```

But I get the error:

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://QuickStart/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-0-2 actorRefSource#355339300]] after [2000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "MyActor$Message".
```

Comment: I have opened an Akka ticket based on this question, given that we recommend this solution in our migration guide. Can be followed here: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23485

Comment: great thanks, my current solutions is to use an actor in the middle that sends me the original sender, but a proper solution would be great

Comment: We did come up with a possible workaround in the ticket, so take a look at that.

Comment: How the foreach and the tell would be use, I don't understand

Comment: If you use `Sink.foreach(elem => myActor ! elem)` and the logic is inside an actor the sender will be picked up implicitly and be self, you could also do `Sink.foreach(elem => myActor.tell(elem, whateverActorRefYouLike))`

Comment: I'm not using the ask inside an actor

Comment: @johanandren so basically I can use `Sink.foreach(elem => myActor ! elem)` and have a new case in my `receive` method like `case elem -> `. What happens once the `elem` msg is received by `myActor`. Do I call the method that the original actor ask was calling?

Comment: Also, `Sink.foreach(elem => myActor ! elem)` throws an error. I am replacing `Sink.actorRef(myActor, NotUsed)` in the `.to` correct?

Comment: Yep, replacing the sink. Can't say what causes the error without details about the error.

Comment: compilation error- type mismatch Found: Nothing => Unit, required: T => Unit

Comment: @Jeff I resolve that problem like this `Sink.foreach[Any]( elem =>  target ! elem)`

Comment: @IgnacioPL the `[Any]` works, but now when i do requests that are greater than the throttle like say 1500 it freezes on me and only 1014 are saved in the db (my actor does db saves). When I try 2, 2 are saved but the response never returns. I'm thinking this is because the response is not sent back to up, possibly?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because `throttler` is a different actor from `MyActor`, and therefore it won't send anything back to the sender. And while your own `myActor` does reply to the sender, internally the incoming message is sent by akka-streams internals, and it would ignore any replies. After all, messages in streams always flow in a single direction (the other direction is reserved for demand).

What you can do is to pass the reference to the original actor with the message:

```
class Sender(myActor: ActorRef)
            (implicit materializer: Materializer) extends Actor {
  val throttler = Source.actorRef[(MyActor.Message, ActorRef)](bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
    .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
    .to(Sink.actorRef(myActor, NotUsed))
    .run()

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case DoIt =>
      throttler ! (MyActor.Message("hello"), self)
    case response: String =>
      println(s"received response: $response")
  }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case (MyActor.Message(msg), originalSender: ActorRef) =>
      val date = LocalDateTime.now()
      println(s"getting: $msg @ $date from $originalSender")
      originalSender ! s"$msg ack"
  }
}

object MyActor {
  case class Message(msg: String)
}
```

Naturally, for this to scale it is probably better to incorporate the original sender into the message class, but the basic approach remains the same.

Comment: I'm still having problems with the ask, because I don't have the ActorRef there.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it with ask alone, since with ask you do not have access to `sender()`. You would need to create an intermediate actor anyway.